# Expected Identifier cell.textLabel.text = @"Facebook" error

Tags: objective-c

I am working in xCode 5.0.2, and I am a novice, so please forgive me for asking such a basic question...

I'm getting an 'Expected identifier' error with the following coding:

```
UITableViewCell *Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[Cell.textLabel.text = @"Facebook"];
[O_TableArray addObject:Cell];
[Cell release];
Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[Cell.textLabel.text = @"Twitter"];
[O_TableArray addObject:Cell];
[Cell release];
Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[Cell.textLabel.text = @"Tumblr"];
[O_TableArray addObject:Cell];
[Cell release];
Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[Cell.textLabel.text = @"Email"];
[O_TableArray addObject:Cell];
[Cell release];
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, but would appreciate any advice you could spare.

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration!

Comment: Why do you create so many cells? Here are the tasks for the next few moth: 1) learn Objective-C, don't just copy random codes without trying to understand them. 2) learn how to populate UITableViews 3) stick to coding conventions

Comment: I don't agree with everyone downvoting & voting to close this question.  Yes, it's a rookie mistake, and the OP should obviously complete a tutorial or class - but it's a well-formed, specific question that includes the error message and the incorrect code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
[Cell.textLabel.text = @"Facebook"];
```

to

```
Cell.textLabel.text = @"Facebook";
```

or

```
[Cell.textLabel setText:@"Facebook"];
```

or

```
[[Cell textLabel] setText:@"Facebook"];
```

(You're incorrectly combining dot and bracket notation.)